# Reverse part of an array using javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in Javascript like so:

```
var v = new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f"...);
```

I would like to reverse it but keep the first two elements, so it would turn into:

```
"a","b",...."f","e","d","c"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var v = new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f");
var newArr = v.splice(0,2).concat(v.reverse()); // get the first 2 out of the array
console.log(newArr);
```

- [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Answer (score 5):

```
v = [].concat( v.slice(0,2), v.slice(2).reverse());
//v --> ["a", "b", "f", "e", "d", "c"]
```

Comment: why the array literal, wouldn't just v.slice(0,2).concat(v.slice(2).reverse()) work?

Comment: @dandavis yeah, sorry, I've tried it in a context where `v` has already been modified. I used `[]` because initially I wanted to assign the result to a new array, as in `var y  = [].concat(...)`

Comment: gotcha, looks good. note sure if slice or splice is faster, but ti's good to have options for when splice is not present.

Comment: @PSL yeah, my solution is slower, by far. http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-splice-array

Answer (score 2):

```
function reverseArrayFromThirdElement(array, copy) {
    var arrayCopy = copy ? array.concat() : array;
    return [array[0], array[1]].concat(
        (arrayCopy.splice(0, 2), arrayCopy.reverse())
    );
}
```

It allows you to choose if you want to keep your array safe from slicing. Pass `copy` as true if you want your array to be internally copied.

Answer (score 1):

Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const reversedEnd = [...v.slice(0, 2), ...v.slice(2).reverse()];

const reversedBeginning = [...v.slice(0, 2).reverse(), ...v.slice(2)];

const reversedMiddle = [...v.slice(0, 2), ...v.slice(2,4).reverse(), ...v.slice(4)];
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like Array.Reverse from C#:

```
const arrayReverse = (arr, index, length) => {
    let temp = arr.slice(index, index + length);
    temp.reverse();

    for (let i = 0, j = index; i < temp.length, j < index + length; i++, j++) {
        arr[j] = temp[i];
    }

    return arr;
};
```

Example:

```
let test = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
test = arrayReverse(test, 4, 2);

console.log(test); // returns [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'e' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For ***inplace*** reversal, this can be done using [**splice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method:

```js
let alp = new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f");
alp.splice(2,4,...alp.slice(2).reverse());
console.log(alp);
```